# Edx-XBlock and mongodb communication

Tags: mongodb, edx

I am new to Edx and its internal architecture.

I am looking for, creating a custom Edx XBlock which has a form. On form submit it will POST a REST-API call and store the result for the student view. Student will see only the result part (not form part)

I am able to create XBlock and call REST API. But I am not clear that how and where I have to store the result part. I believe it should be stored inside edx mongodb (Please correct me if I am wrong). If so, how should I access the db from XBlock.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XBlocks, data storage is handled via the XBlock fields. You set the fields value, and the framework will automatically store the value in the database, and restore it when the XBlock is reloaded.

Where and how the values are stored depends on the scope of each XBlock field. See the [documentation about XBlock fields scope](http://xblock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/fields.html).